In Markov Decision Process, how to understand the calculation of the average length of episode?
In the Sec. 13.2 of RL: An Introduction (Sutton & Barto), the concept of average episode length is discussed for both episodic MDP and continuing MDP.
In an episodic MDP, the average length of an episode can be calculated as the sum of the stationary distribution of states under policy $\pi$, denoted as $\sum_{s}d^{\pi}(s)$. In a continuing MDP, the average episode length is defined as 1. How to understand the calculation of the average length in such two cases?

I only see your reference claimed "In the episodic case, the constant of proportionality is the average length of an episode, and in the continuing case it is 1", where you see it claimed "the average length of an episode can be calculated as the sum of the stationary distribution of states"?

@cinch Hi, thanks for your reply. I see this statement in the policy gradient tutorial. It claims "In the episodic case, the constant of proportionality is the average length of an episode; in the continuing case, it is 1."
